# Which Amazon AMI for a Rails app in a Docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am looking to deploy my Rails app to an Amazon Web Services AMI, and I want to package my app in a Docker image. I know Docker should be on Linux in production, but there are several different flavors of Linux there and I don't know which one to use. Does it matter? Or as long as I have Docker Engine installed, will any of them work?

Thanks for any advice you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your docker container directly to AWS with the AWS Container service. Normally you use a minimized Linux System like CoreOS to run your container.

Here the Amazon service manage your instances and container.

https://aws.amazon.com/de/ecs/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks like the container service works with your existing EC2 instances, yes? But it seems like as long as your EC2 is a version of Linux that Docker can run on, you're good to go.

Comment: No! Try it out ;) "not on your existing" instances. The AWS system generate and manage that instances.

Comment: Looks like they bill you based on the EC2 resources you use though, right? Otherwise how do you know how much capacity you have left? Or am I thinking about it all wrong? I'm super new to Docker and AWS both. Thanks again for your replies!

Comment: You define a maximum of instances for your container. https://aws.amazon.com/de/ecs/ there is a video which explain it. The AWS monitor your application and if you need more power you get more instances and its high scalable. Try it out its the best way ;)